# how to solve multi step problem in my css file?

Tags: html, css

I am creating a multi step form for my php pages.
working but that the previous stage line color not changed .

```css
.container
{
  width:100%;
}
.progressbar
{
  counter-reset :step;
}
.progressbar li{
  list-style:none;
  float:left;
  width :20%;
  position :relative;
  text-align:center;

}
.progressbar li:before
{
  content:counter(step);
  counter-increment:step;
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  line-height :30px;
  border:1px solid #ddd;
  display:block;
  text-align:center;
  margin:0 auto 10px auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color:white;
}
.progressbar li:after
{
  content:'';
  position:absolute; 
  width:100%;
  height:1px; 
  background-color:blue;
  top :15px;
  left:-50%;
  z-index:-1;
}
.progressbar li:first-child:after{
  content:none;
}
.progressbar li.active
{
  color:green;
}
.progressbar li.active:before{
  border-color:green;
}
.progressbar li.active:before{  
  background: #27AE60;
  color: blue;
}
.progressbar li.active:after{
  background: #27AE60;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"> 
  <ul class="progressbar">
    <li>Registration</li>
    <li>Application</li>
    <li class="active">Upload Documents</li>
    <li>Payment</li>
    <li>Completed</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

problem was i am in the third stage 2-3 line (green) but 1-2 line shows blue. need help.
what mistake i have done in my css file. how to solve this. once stage completed the line color changed to be green line else blue line.

[image]

Comment: CSS can not select “to the left”. You can not format the first two list items based on that the third one has a specific class. The easiest way to handle this would be to give those finished steps a specific class as well, in your application logic.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you change your **css** a bit it would work. You should add this to your **css**

```
.progressbarr li:after{color: green;}
```

but you also need to delete some css code because else it is over righting

Comment: I did not have any time to test my answer but maybe it will help you

Comment: I don't see a reason how that possibly could happen, I'm sorry

Comment: @anbesivam you dont have any red color in your style. So I really don't get why it is turning red

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to accomplish here is not possible using just css.
You need a way to give give a new class or let the class 'active' on the 'visited' steps.
The way you are, you can only style the before and the after of one element letting the others without the active styles.
You can try it giving the 'active' class to step 1 en 2.